# Efficient way to create DataFrame with different column types

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, dataframe, numpy

I need to read data from numeric Postgres table and create DataFrame accordingly.

The default way Pandas is doing it is by using `DataFrame.from_records`:

```
df = DataFrame.from_records(data,
                            columns=columns,
                            coerce_float=coerce_float)
```

When `data` looks like:

```
[(0.16275345863180396, 0.16275346), (0.6356328878675244, 0.6356329)...]
```

And `columns` looks like:

```
['a', 'b']
```

The problem is that the generated DataFrame ignores the original Posgres types: `double precision` and `real`.

As I use huge DataFrames and my data is mostly `real` I'd like to explicitly specify the column types.

So I tried:

```
df = DataFrame.from_records(np.array(data, dtype=columns),
                            coerce_float=coerce_float)
```

When `data` is the same, but `columns` looks like:

```
[('a', 'float64'), ('b', 'float32')]
```

(types are extracted from Postgres as a part of query and converted to Numpy dtypes)

This approach works, but DataFrame construction is 2-3 times slower (for 2M rows DataFrames it takes several seconds), because `np.array` generation is for some reason very slow. In real life I have 10-200 columns mostly `float32`.

What is the fastest way to construct DataFrame with specified column types?

Comment: Did you try `pandas.read_sql_query`? It accepts a `dtype` option to specify the column types.

Comment: `read_sql_query` `dtype` argument is added recently and it feels like a workaround - it is casting the types of already created DF.....

Comment: What is the value of `coerce_float`? I've checked with floats (same as your example data) and do not see any big speed difference between direct creating or going throung numpy. If I use `Decimal` in sample data, then the difference in creation speed is obvious.

Comment: Why don't you change dtypes after dataframe creation? `pd.DataFrame.from_records(data).astype({'a': 'float64', 'b': 'float32'})`

Comment: I am trying to optimize DF creation. Creating DF twice as big (float64) to just change it later doesn't make sense....

Comment: @Miro Can you just use float32 for all the columns? Many times the loss in precision is acceptable for the specific end use.

Comment: Unfortunately no - one of the columns is always time (which is converted to index). In some cases, there are some float64 columns

Comment: @Miro can you put the float32 columns in a separate auxiliary dataframe to help save space. This float32 dataframe would match by row number to the primary dataframe that has the index on it?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the data columns and its types already, then following format will help to generate data frame with specified datatypes.

```py
    pd.DataFrame(data, columns = columnList, dtype = np.dtype([('type1','type2')]))
```

Comment: I didn't know you can specify multiple dtypes in constructor. And it doesn't seem to work also - I am getting an error: `TypeError: Field elements must be tuples with at most 3 elements` when the tuple contains more than 3 types.

Comment: From Pandas docs: `Only a single dtype is allowed.`

Answer (score 0):

You can read the using the standard [`psycopg2`](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/) driver. Here, you can [register your own type caster](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/advanced.html#type-casting-of-sql-types-into-python-objects) to convert `REAL` to `np.float32` instead of the default python `float` (the OID of the data type - `700` for `REAL` - can either be obtained as described in the link or taken from [here](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/include/catalog/pg_type.dat)):

```
import psycopg2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

real_oid = 700
REAL2FLOAT32 = psycopg2.extensions.new_type((real_oid,), 'REAL2FLOAT32', lambda val, cur: np.float32(val))
psycopg2.extensions.register_type(REAL2FLOAT32)

with psycopg2.connect('postgresql://user:pwd@localhost:5432/test') as con:
    with con.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute('select 0.16275345863180396::double precision, 0.16275346::real')
        # print(cur.description) # to get the OID for real
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['a', 'b'])
```

Output of `df.info()`:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   a       1 non-null      float64
 1   b       1 non-null      float32
dtypes: float32(1), float64(1)
memory usage: 140.0 bytes
```

If you like, you can integrate this directly into pandas that uses SQLAlchemy in the background like this:

```
import sqlalchemy

real_oid = 700
REAL2FLOAT32 = psycopg2.extensions.new_type((real_oid,), "REAL2FLOAT32", lambda val, cur: np.float32(val))
psycopg2.extensions.register_type(REAL2FLOAT32)

with sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql://user:pwd@localhost:5432/test').connect() as con:
    df = pd.read_sql_query('select 0.16275345863180396::double precision, 0.16275346::real', con)
```

---

As for speed, [`asyncpg`](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/index.html) [claims to be much faster than psycopg2](https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg#performance). Here you should be able to use [`set_type_codec`](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/api/index.html?highlight=set_type_codec#asyncpg.connection.Connection.set_type_codec) to make your own conversion as shown in [this example](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/usage.html#example-decoding-numeric-columns-as-floats), but I didn't test it.

Comment: Type casters of  psycopg2 are much slower than just casting the type with `astype`. I haven't tried the `asyncpg` - maybe it's an interesting idea.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this is probably helpful:

```
data = [(0.16275345863180396, 0.16275346), (0.6356328878675244, 0.6356329)]
columns = ['a', 'b']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns, dtype='float64').astype({'b':'float32'})
print(df.info()
```

Output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   a       2 non-null      float64
 1   b       2 non-null      float32
dtypes: float32(1), float64(1)
memory usage: 152.0 bytes
```

Answer (score -1):

Try connecting to the Postgresql database and read directly to pandas data frame. Not sure if you already tried this way.

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2 as pg
connection= pg.connect("dbname='dbname' user='pguser' host='127.0.0.1' port='15432' password='password'")
df = pd.read_sql('select * from table', connection)
```

Comment: `read_sql` is using `DataFrame.from_records` internally and is not treating types properly (Postgres `real` is converted to `np.float64`) - exactly the reason why I am dealing with this problem in the 1st place.

Comment: python does not have `real` as datatype, it will treat as `np.float64`. if you know datatypes of columns already try this.`types_dict = {'col_1': str,'col_2': float,'col_3': bool}
pandas_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols).astype(types_dict)`

Comment: It means I cannot create the DF properly from the beginning - which is a waste of resources. Creating a 100 columns DF with double, just to convert it a second later to `np.float32` - is a huge waste.